# How to bind a layout_width and layout_height using data binding in Android

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying to bind a boolean that indicates to an ImageView if the screen size is small, so it shrinks if I need more space for other components. I'm using the [DataBinding Library](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/data-binding/guide.html) to do so.

My layout whose width and height depends on this boolean:

```
...
<data>
    ...
    <variable name="smallScreen" type="boolean"/>
    ...
</data>
...
<ImageView
android:layout_width="@{smallScreen ? @dimen/img_small_screen_size : @dimen/img_big_screen_size}"
android:layout_height="@{smallScreen ? @dimen/img_small_screen_size : @dimen/img_big_screen_size}"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:contentDescription="@{message}"
android:src="@{image}"
android:scaleType="center"
tools:src="@drawable/img_message_private"/>
...
```

If I just try to build my project like this, the compiler says layout_width cannot accept type float. Fair enough, I use the BindingAdapter class to create a float enter for layout attributes, as follows:

```
...
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, float width) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = (int) width;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}

@BindingAdapter("android:layout_height")
public static void setLayoutHeight(View view, float height) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = (int) height;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
...
```

That allows my project to build. But when the layout is finally being rendered, I fall in the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #21: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

Just for information, my dimensions are set in dp units, as follows:

```
<dimen name="img_small_screen_size">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="img_big_screen_size">208dp</dimen>
```

Does someone know how can I override the layout_width attribute so I can use databind with it directly, using dimensions?

Answer (score 8):

You should add a default value, i.e.,

```
android:layout_width="@{smallScreen ? @dimen/img_small_screen_size : @dimen/img_big_screen_size, default=wrap_content}"
```

Comment: Thanks. setting default value solves my problem. But I have one doubt, default value will never execute, either first or second value will run then why default value?

Comment: Thanks! Your post has helped me as well!

Comment: @Shubham it all depends on when the op actually binds the "smallScreen" variable to the layout. If it is later than the first layout pass the aforementioned error will be thrown. Also, keep in mind that the default value can come in very handy for the layout preview if you don't want to or can use the appropriate tools attribute.

Answer (score 6):

I just figured it out as I wrote my question. I just used another attribute to bind the one I wanted changed, the code ended like this:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="@{smallScreen ? @dimen/img_small_screen_size : @dimen/img_big_screen_size}"
android:layout_height="@{smallScreen ? @dimen/img_small_screen_size : @dimen/img_big_screen_size}"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:contentDescription="@{message}"
android:src="@{image}"
android:scaleType="center"
tools:src="@drawable/img_message_private"/>
```

So my BindingAdapters became this:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, float width) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = (int) width;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}

@BindingAdapter("android:layout_height")
public static void setLayoutHeight(View view, float height) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = (int) height;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: You can also use "android:layout_width" as well. You don't have to use your own namespace.

Comment: Now your answer looks same as question