# Android Data Binding : conditional formatting to set layout_weight

Tags: android, android-databinding

How to set layout_weight in xml using android data bindning? in dimens folder we provide values as in dp / sp.

Comment: Why databinding is required for your task?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is a binding adapter that works for me, your view does need to be inside a LinearLayout, which I think it will be if you are wanting to set the weight:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_weight")
fun setLayoutWeight(view: View, weight: Float) {
    val layoutParams = view.layoutParams as? LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    layoutParams?.let {
        it.weight = weight
        view.layoutParams = it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this method to the java file related to the xml:

```
    @BindingAdapter("android:layout_weight")
public static void setLayoutWeight(View view, int weight) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.weight = weight;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same technique as for `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`, which has been discussed previously:

[How to bind a layout_width and layout_height using data binding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863729/how-to-bind-a-layout-width-and-layout-height-using-data-binding-in-android)

You must create your own BindingAdapter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@BindingAdapter("layout_weight")
    fun setLayoutWeight(view: View, weight: Float) {
        view.layoutParams = TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                     TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                     weight)
    }
```